# How do I reference one game object in a script attached to another?

Tags: unity, c#

This is all in Unity, with C#.

I have attached a script to my player that should destroy a `TreeGroup` (as in a forest) whenever I press 'Q' and instantiate one when I press 'E'.

Here is the code:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DisableTrees : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {
            //Disable Trees on A Keypress

            Debug.Log("Trees Disabled!");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) {
            //Enable Trees on E Keypress

            Debug.Log("Trees Enabled!");
        }

    }
}
```

How do I access and find my 'TreeGroup' object group while script not being attached to 'TreeGroup' but my character instead and then Destroy on Q Keypress?
And how do I Instantiate it?

Comment: Destroying all the trees in the scene? Or is the player pointing to a specific set of trees? Is the instantiation happening at a specific spot?

Comment: Imagine a huge box collider around the player which refers to a vegetation draw distance, vegetation in box is being instantiated and vegetation out of the box is being destroyed, to avoid showing everything at once, but instead only part of your field of view.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

- Create a variable `public GameObject TreeGroup` in your DisableTrees behavior. The variable will now appear as a field in the inspector of DisableTrees. You can then drag the TreeGroup game object to it.
- Use [`GameObject.Find`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) to find the tree group by its name. But keep in mind that this method is very slow on larger scene graphs.
- Add an unique tag to the tree group and use [`GameObject.FindWithTag`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)
- When the TreeGroup is a child or parent of the GameObject from where you need it and the TreeGroup has some unique component, you can use [`GetComponentInParent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInParent.html) / [`GetComponentInChildren`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) and use the returned component to navigate to its GameObject.

Comment: You can also use the [SerializeField] attribute for the first option, declared before the variable, rather than make it public.

Answer (score 0):

You can tag the tree in your group and then use FindGameObjectWithTag to get a list of all them.  Next iterate over the list and destroy the game objects.