# How can I edit a float that is in another script? (In C#)

Tags: unity, c#

So basically, I have one script for the UI, which holds the float, score. Then I also have another script on my coin that detects when the player collides with it. What I want it to do is change the value of score, but I don't know how to change it, as it is in the UI script. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't forget to search for [similar questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/119973/39518) first. For basic stuff like this, you'll find it's often already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to help you solve a programming question if you don't provide any code...

Here is the idea, supposing the script attached to your UI is called `UIScript`

```
// Coin script

// Drag & Drop the gameobject holding the `UIScript` into the inspector
public UIScript theUIScript;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    // Your code when a collision is detected ...

    theUIScript.AddPoints( 10 ) ;
}
```

---

```
// UI Script

public UnityEngine.UI.Text scoreText;

private int score = 0 ;

public void AddPoints( int points )
{
    score += points ;
    scoreText = score.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but sometimes the script acts twice and adds double the points and sometimes it doesn't, how do I fix that?

Comment: Hey Miles; at this point, you should be able to generalize how to add double points. We're not here to program everything for you. In all honestly, if you have trouble generalizing what you already know to the question in your comment here, you're going to have a tough time when you get to really tricky stuff in game development.

Comment: I just want to know how to make sure it only runs once, I literally installed unity yesterday, I'm a beginner.

Comment: My best guess without seeing your code/scene is that the collision is happening twice, so the solution is either to turn off collisions for the coin after the first hit or to ignore subsequent collisions. For example add a variable to the coin script to track if it's been "collected": `private boolean _isCollected = false;` and check that in the collision handler: `if (!_isCollected) { theUIScript.AddPoints(10); _isCollided = true; }`

Comment: Also delete  the gameobject once it's been collected, that way it can't collide anymore.